# javascript form cookies - select only opening cookie for first 10 indexes

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies

I have never used cookies before, so I am using a peice of code I am very unfamiliar with.

It was working all fine, until I noticed just now that for select boxes, it is not working for any values after the tenth index. (for index 10 and above).

I have looked at the cookie stored on my system, and it appears t be saving them correctly. (I saw select10) ETC stored properly.

When it runs onload of body however, it is not loading in the values properly.

Here is the cookie code I am using:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

<!-- Begin

var expDays = 100;
var exp = new Date(); 

exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (expDays*24*60*60*1000));

function getCookieVal (offset) {  
    var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);  
    if (endstr == -1) { endstr = document.cookie.length; }
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
}



function GetCookie (name) {  
    var arg = name + "=";  
    var alen = arg.length;  
    var clen = document.cookie.length;  
    var i = 0;  

    while (i < clen) {    
        var j = i + alen;    
        if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg) return getCookieVal (j);    
        i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;    
        if (i == 0) break;   
    }  

    return null;
}



function SetCookie (name, value) {  
    var argv = SetCookie.arguments;  
    var argc = SetCookie.arguments.length;  
    var expires = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null;  
    var path = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null;  
    var domain = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null;  
    var secure = (argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false;  

    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) + 
    ((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) + 
    ((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) +  
    ((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) +    
    ((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");
}

// use the following code to call it:
//  <body onLoad="cookieForms('open', 'form_1', 'form_2', 'form_n')" onUnLoad="cookieForms('save', 'form_1', 'form_2', 'form_n')">

function cookieForms() {  
    var mode = cookieForms.arguments[0];

    for(f=1; f<cookieForms.arguments.length; f++) {
        formName = cookieForms.arguments[f];

        if(mode == 'open') {    
            cookieValue = GetCookie('saved_'+formName);

            if(cookieValue != null) {
                var cookieArray = cookieValue.split('#cf#');

                if(cookieArray.length == document[formName].elements.length) {
                    for(i=0; i<document[formName].elements.length; i++) {
                        if(cookieArray[i].substring(0,6) == 'select') { document[formName].elements[i].options.selectedIndex = cookieArray[i].substring(7, cookieArray[i].length-1); }
                        else if((cookieArray[i] == 'cbtrue') || (cookieArray[i] == 'rbtrue')) { document[formName].elements[i].checked = true; }
                        else if((cookieArray[i] == 'cbfalse') || (cookieArray[i] == 'rbfalse')) { document[formName].elements[i].checked = false; }
                        else { document[formName].elements[i].value = (cookieArray[i]) ? cookieArray[i] : ''; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(mode == 'save') {    
            cookieValue = '';

            for(i=0; i<document[formName].elements.length; i++) {
                fieldType = document[formName].elements[i].type;

                if(fieldType == 'password') { passValue = ''; }
                else if(fieldType == 'checkbox') { passValue = 'cb'+document[formName].elements[i].checked; }
                else if(fieldType == 'radio') { passValue = 'rb'+document[formName].elements[i].checked; }
                else if(fieldType == 'select-one') { passValue = 'select'+document[formName].elements[i].options.selectedIndex; }
                else { passValue = document[formName].elements[i].value; }
                cookieValue = cookieValue + passValue + '#cf#';
            }
            cookieValue = cookieValue.substring(0, cookieValue.length-4); // Remove last delimiter
            SetCookie('saved_'+formName, cookieValue, exp);     
        }   
    }
}

//  End -->
</script>
```

I beleive the problem lies with the following line, found about 3/4 of the way down the code block above (line 68):

```
if(cookieArray[i].substring(0,6) == 'select') { document[formName].elements[i].options.selectedIndex = cookieArray[i].substring(7, cookieArray[i].length-1); }
```

Just for reference, here is the opening body tag I am using:

```
<body style="text-align:center;" onload="cookieForms('open', 'ramsform', 'decksform', 'hullsform', 'crewform', 'shipwrightform'); Swap(crew0z,'crew0i'); Swap(crew1z,'crew1i'); Swap(crew2z,'crew2i'); Swap(crew3z,'crew3i'); Swap(crew4z,'crew4i'); Swap(crew5z,'crew5i'); Swap(crew6z,'crew6i'); Swap(crew7z,'crew7i'); Swap(crew8z,'crew8i'); Swap(crew9z,'crew9i');" onunload="cookieForms('save', 'ramsform', 'decksform', 'hullsform', 'crewform', 'shipwrightform');">
```

(Please ignore the swap()'s as they are unrelated)

Page I am working on can be found: http://webhostlet.com/POP.htm

Comment: Style comment: don't put so much code in the `onXXX=` attributes, have them call a function that does everything.

Comment: Are you interested in jQuery solutions? There's a plugin that can save and restore the contents of a form in a cookie.

Comment: hey barmar. I know the style is awful. This is kind of my first time back to anything coding-related in years. You should see the state of my javascript running this calculator, good god! lol.

I am interested in anything which makes this work to be honest. I have several forms, all of which I need to be stored in cookies. I dont understnad what most the lines are really doing other than vague ideas in the code i posted above, which is why I cannot disect it enough. I am pretty sure the problem lies with the one line I pulled out though. It must be only taking the first character from selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both the `open` and `save` codes, change:

```
document[formName].elements[i].options.selectedIndex
```

to:

```
document[formName].elements[i].selectedIndex
```

`options` is an array of all the options, the `selectedIndex` property belongs to the `select` element that contains them.

Change:

```
cookieArray[i].substring(7, cookieArray[i].length-1)
```

to:

```
cookieArray[i].substring(6)
```

You were off by 1 because you forgot that it's 0-based counting. The second argument isn't needed, it defaults to the rest of the string.

The reason it worked for the first 10 menu items is a quirk of substring: if the second argument is lower than the first, it swaps them! So `"select5".substring(7, 6)` is treated as `"select5".substring(6, 7)`, which gets the last character of the string. But for the longer strings, it was `` `"select35".substring(7, 7) ``, which is an empty string.

Comment: hey, thanks. I have done this, but it hasn't solved the problem, sorry. Selecting any of the first 10 items in the options lists works fine, but selecting anything after that does not.

I looked at the stored cookie, and it appears to save them fine. It just doesnt read out fine for some reason if the index is 10 or higher. I am guessing its a problem with the substring part of this line:

    if(cookieArray[i].substring(0,6) == 'select') { document[formName].elements[i].selectedIndex = cookieArray[i].substring(7, cookieArray[i].length-1); }

in the open code.

Comment: BTW you can see a live version of this at: http://webhostlet.com/POP.htm

If you select a low-down option in the check boxes in the table on the right, they are not working if you refresh the page. the top 10 however, are worknig fine.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much. :)
Thats the problem with using code you didnt write, when it goes wrong you have no idea where to start lol. Well i dont anyway lol. Thanks! :D